# Set background colour to page

Tags: html, css, asp.net, styling

I am using .net framework 4.5. I have created a web form, that has a table. I am using one image as background image. That image is nothing but a white bar having gray at both left and right corner. But when I am using, able to see white my page having a gray bar at both corner with white background.

1. Getting:    white background gray bar white page
2. Want:    I want Gray background white page

I don't want a white background.

```
<table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="6" style="background-image: url(../Images/bar.jpg)" width="900">
   <tr>
       <td>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

What shall I do?

Comment: can you share your html as a image

Comment: I am not able to see any option for sharing image here.

Comment: If that's all your image does then use CSS

Answer (score 5):

According what i understood you are asking how to change the background of the table from white to grey.You just have to simply change your code from

```
 <table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" border="0" cellpadding="3"
    cellspacing="6" style="background-image: url(../Images/bar.jpg)"
    width="900">
```

to this

```
<table align="center" bgcolor="#808080" border="0" cellpadding="3"
        cellspacing="6" style="background-image: url(../Images/bar.jpg)"
        width="900">
```

Where i have changed the background of the table from #ffffff (which is the color code of white) to #808080(which is the color code of gray)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want exactly. Try the following solution.

```
<table classname="custom-table" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="6">
   <tr>
     <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.custom-table {
   background-image: url(../Images/bar.jpg);
   background-repeat: repeat;
   width:900px;
   border:0px;
   background-color:#fff;
}
```